# Using removeActionListener but not removing - JAVA

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I have created part of a Tic-Tac-Toe game, and I am trying to make sure the "Player VS Player" button becomes disabled once a game is started. I am new to Java swing and all of the graphics, so please, any help is appreciated. I have used .removeActionListener, but it seems to not do anything (or anything I notice). My code probably looks very bad to some of you, but as I said, I am new to this. Some of the imports may not be needed now, but I plan on using them later.
Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Object;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.Frame;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.lang.Thread;
import java.util.EventObject;
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.*;

class ticTacToe implements ActionListener
{
  public static JFrame menuFrame = new JFrame("Tic-Tac-Toe");
  public static JPanel menu = new JPanel();
  public static JButton instruct = new JButton("Instructions"), pvp = new JButton("Player VS. Player"), pvc = new JButton("Player VS. Computer");
  public static String pOne = "bla", pTwo = "bla";
  public static boolean namesEntered = false;
  public static JFrame pvpFrame = new JFrame (pOne+" "+"VS."+" "+pTwo);
  public static JPanel board = new JPanel (), turns = new JPanel();
  public static JLabel turn1 = new JLabel (pOne+" has taken 0 turn(s)."), turn2 = new JLabel (pTwo+" has taken 0 turn(s).");
  public static JButton btn1 = new JButton (), btn2 = new JButton (), btn3 = new JButton (), btn4 = new JButton (), btn5 = new JButton (), btn6 = new JButton (), btn7 = new JButton (), btn8 = new JButton (), btn9 = new JButton ();
  public static int choice = 3;
  public static Font f = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40);

  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    instruct.addActionListener(new Instructions());
    pvp.addActionListener(new playerVSPlayer());
    pvc.addActionListener(new Action());
    menu();
  }

  public static void menu ()//the main menu of the game
  {
    menu.setLayout(new FlowLayout());//arranges the layout of the buttons on the panel

    menu.add(instruct);//adds the instruction button
    menu.add(pvp);//adds the player vs player button
    menu.add(pvc);//adds the player vs computer button

    menuFrame.add(menu);//creates the panel
    menuFrame.setSize(450, 78);
    menuFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);//sets the location to the centre of the screen
    menuFrame.setVisible(true);//makes the menu visible
    menuFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//extis program when window is closed
  }
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)//detection of the clicked button
  {
    if (e.getSource().equals(instruct))
    {
      instructions();
    }
    else if (e.getSource().equals(pvp))
    { 
      if (e.getSource().equals(btn1))
      {
        btn1.setFont(f);
        btn1.setText("X");
        btn1.removeActionListener(new playerVSPlayer());
      }
      else
      {
        players();
        if (!pOne.equals("0")&&!pTwo.equals("0"))
        {
          firstTurn();
        }
        if (namesEntered==true&&choice==1)
        {
          gameBoard();
          btn1.addActionListener(new playerVSPlayer());
        }
        pvp.removeActionListener(new playerVSPlayer());
      }
    }
  }

  public static void instructions ()
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Instructions");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(300,145);
    JLabel label = new JLabel ("The goal of this game is to be the first player that ");
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel ("gets 3 X's or O's in a row diagonally, vertically, or");
    JLabel label3 = new JLabel ("horizontally. It is possible to tie, by having all");
    JLabel label4 = new JLabel ("spaces played with no spots left to win. Click a");
    JLabel label5 = new JLabel ("space to enter your X or O.");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(label2);
    panel.add(label3);
    panel.add(label4);
    panel.add(label5);
  }

  public static void players ()
  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Player One, please enter a word no longer than 4 letters, representing your username for this game.");
    pOne = in.nextLine();
    if (pOne.equals("0"))
    {
      System.out.println("You have cancelled the match. Please choose an option in the main menu, or close the main menu.");
    }
    else {
      while (pOne.length()>4||pOne.length()<1)
      {
        System.out.println("Player One, your username MUST be between 1 and 4 letters long.");
        pOne = in.nextLine();
      }
    }
    if (!pOne.equals("0"))
    {
      System.out.println("Player Two, please enter a word no longer than 4 letters, representing your username for this game.");
      pTwo = in.nextLine();
      if (pTwo.equals("0"))
      {
        System.out.println("You have cancelled the match. Please choose an option in the main menu, or close the main menu.");
      }
      else {
        while (pTwo.length()>4||pTwo.length()<1)
        {
          System.out.println("Player Two, your username MUST be between 1 and 4 letters long.");
          pTwo = in.nextLine();
        }
      }
    }
    if (!pOne.equals("0")&&!pTwo.equals("0"))
    {
      namesEntered= true;
    }
  }
  public static void gameBoard ()
  {
    pvpFrame = new JFrame (pOne+" "+"VS."+" "+pTwo);
    pvpFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    pvpFrame.setVisible(true);
    pvpFrame.setSize(600,400);
    pvpFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    board.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
    turns.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    pvpFrame.add(board);
    pvpFrame.add(turns);
    turn1 = new JLabel (pOne+" has taken 0 turns.");
    turn2 = new JLabel (pTwo+" has taken 0 turns.");
    turns.add(turn1);
    turns.add(turn2);
    board.add(btn1);
    board.add(btn2);
    board.add(btn3);
    board.add(btn4);
    board.add(btn5);
    board.add(btn6);
    board.add(btn7);
    board.add(btn8);
    board.add(btn9);
  }

  public static void firstTurn ()
  { 
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println(pOne+" will be X and "+pTwo+" will be O. Enter 1 if you would like to continue. Enter 0 if you would like to cancel this match and return to the main menu.");
    choice = in.nextInt();
    while (choice!=0&&choice!=1)
    {
      System.out.println("Your choice did not match 1 or 0. Please enter your choice again.");
      choice = in.nextInt();
    }
    if (choice==0)
    {
      System.out.println("You have cancelled the match. Please choose an option in the main menu, or close the main menu.");
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

```
 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)//detection of the clicked button
  {
    if (e.getSource().equals(instruct))
    {
      instructions(); // This just runs the instruction panel
    }
    else if (e.getSource().equals(pvp))
    { 
      if (e.getSource().equals(btn1))
      {
        btn1.setFont(f);
        btn1.setText("X");
        btn1.removeActionListener(new playerVSPlayer());
      }
      else
      {
        players();
        if (!pOne.equals("0")&&!pTwo.equals("0"))
        {
          firstTurn();
        }
        if (namesEntered==true&&choice==1)
        {
          gameBoard();
          pvp.setEnabled(false); // my goal here is to make the button no longer usable once the 
//game starts, but I also need to make sure later that i can use the button once this game is closed
          btn1.addActionListener(new playerVSPlayer());
        }

      }
    }
  }
```

The problem is, that does not disable the button

Comment: I'd change the entire program set up if it were up to me. You are grossly over-using static modifier within your program suggesting that something is very wrong. Also, I'm not sure that I'd be swapping listeners as you're doing. Rather I'd set button Actions.

Comment: Answer changed since I now realize that all you want to do is disable the button.

Answer (score 4):

I have several issues with your code, but as far as your question is concerned, there are two main issues:

- First as Christian points out, you are not adding and removing the same instance. I'm not sure if this can be alleviated by giving the class an equals and hashCode override, and I must test this.
- But even more important, you seem to expect the class's actionPerformed to act, when you don't appear to add it to any buttons. No where do I see `addActionListener(this)`. Having said that, I try to avoid making my GUI "view" classes implement listener interfaces.
- A better solution perhaps would be swapping JButton AbstractActions via the `setAction(...)` method. Think of AbstractActions as if they were ActionListeners on steroids, since they can do everything that an ActionListener can do and then some. Do this and you won't have to worry about removing prior listeners since a button can have one and only one Action.

Other issues:

- Your program grossly over-uses the static modifier. While static fields and methods probably won't matter in small programs, they're not a good habit to get into since they don't "scale" well. In other words, if you create large and complex programs (and if you stick with Java, you will), over-use of static fields and methods increases the potential complexity and limits the inheritance potential of your classes of your programs making them very difficult to debug or enhance. It's a good habit to avoid over-use of static modifier except in the certain situations where it is definitely called for.
- You're mixing a Swing GUI with a console program which is a dangerous thing to do. Much better would be to get all user input via the GUI, and leave the console output for debugging purposes (if that) only.

---

**Edit**
Yep, if you override equals and hashCode so that all Listeners of one type are the same, then you can remove them as you're trying to do.

For example check this test code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestActionListeners extends JPanel {
   private JButton button = new JButton("Button");

   public TestActionListeners() {
      add(button);

      button.addActionListener(new Listener1());
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      TestActionListeners mainPanel = new TestActionListeners();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class Listener1 implements ActionListener {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      System.out.println("in listener 1");

      AbstractButton button = (AbstractButton) e.getSource();

      button.removeActionListener(new Listener1());
      button.addActionListener(new Listener2());
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      return obj instanceof Listener1;
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
      return Listener1.class.hashCode();
   }
}

class Listener2 implements ActionListener {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      System.out.println("in listener 2");

      AbstractButton button = (AbstractButton) e.getSource();

      button.removeActionListener(new Listener2());
      button.addActionListener(new Listener1());
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      return obj instanceof Listener2;
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
      return Listener2.class.hashCode();
   }
}
```

Having said this, I don't recommend that you do this but rather swap AbstractActions via `setAction(...)`.

---

**Edit 2**
I'm an idiot for not carefully reading your question. If this is your goal:

> and I am trying to make sure the "Player VS Player" button becomes disabled once a game is started:

Then all you need to do is set the button **or its Action** disabled. i.e.,

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DisableAButton extends JPanel {
   private JButton disableMeButton1 = new JButton("Disable Me 1");
   private JButton disableMeButton2 = new JButton(new DisableMe2Action("Disable Me 2"));

   public DisableAButton() {
      disableMeButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            AbstractButton buttonSource = (AbstractButton) e.getSource();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(buttonSource, "DisableMe1 ActionListener!");

            buttonSource.setEnabled(false);
         }
      });

      add(disableMeButton1);
      add(disableMeButton2);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      DisableAButton mainPanel = new DisableAButton();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("DisableAButton");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class DisableMe2Action extends AbstractAction {
   public DisableMe2Action(String name) {
      super(name);
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      JComponent source = (JComponent) e.getSource();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(source, "DisableMe2 Action!");

      setEnabled(false);
   }
}
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying, I think the problem is I am not skilled enough with graphics in Java. Would you like me to paste part of what I tried to accomplish the same thing? (it does not work)

Comment: @Mr_Wizerman69: sure, more information would be useful. Note that you should edit your original question, don't delete the code that's there, but add any new code to the bottom.

Comment: @Mr_Wizerman69: your question with your second code is why doesn't the pvp JButton get disabled, but based on that code, it's not possible to tell. If this were my problem, I'd try to debug that code to see if the listener code is even ever called, if the if conditions are met. I also avoid using one ActionListener for everything since it leads to the creation of a "switch-board" ActionListener (like you've created above) which are a witch to try to debug. Instead, create a listener for each unique type of button.

Comment: @Mr_Wizerman69: Finally, for better help, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I will create a listener for each button, but will i be able to disable the pvp button?

Comment: @Mr_Wizerman69: if done correctly, yes, of course you can disable the button. The key is in the details of your code.

Comment: I created the listener by: public static ActionListener playerVSPlayer = new playerVSPlayer(); - however when i try to change the name, and change everywhere that is called to the new name, it produces an error, any ideas? Also, the place I disable the button is being called because it produces the game board but does not disable the button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68153/discussion-between-mr-wizerman69-and-hovercraft-full-of-eels).

Answer (score 1):

you should use the same instance to call add and remove.
therefor store the listeners in a field

Comment: so should i make a variable, for example,  `public static ActionListener playerVSPlayer = new ActionListener();`?

Comment: yes that is right (of course you could improve your oop as well)

Comment: Ok thanks, however I get this error when I use that variable:
1 error found:
[line: 60]
Error: java.awt.event.ActionListener is abstract; cannot be instantiated - I did this after making the variable: `pvp.removeActionListener(new playerVSPlayer);`

Comment: sorry i mean your actual listener???? ``` btn1.addActionListener(new playerVSPlayer());```

Comment: can we move this to a quick chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68146/discussion-between-mr-wizerman69-and-christian-dietrich).